# Any way to run a script in tandem with my Flask web page on App engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I recently got my Flask site up and running, which uses data that's scraped from several other web sites and displays it on my own. My issue is that I don't know how to run the web scraping script during the deploy. It runs indefinitely and updates every minute, which is crucial to what I'm working on. Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scripts that run indefinitely are not a good fit for App Engine or similar products like Cloud Functions or Cloud Run. These products are meant to respond to a single request and may spin up new instances to handle new requests, and then spin the instance down.

If you need to run a script continuously, [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute) might be a better fit. Another alternative would be to reconfigure your script to be something that can be run repeatedly, and make it a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions) that is called repeatedly by [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler).